# Duda con Modelos en Django

Tags: django, django-models

Hola tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
class Cotizacion(TimeStampedModel):
    codigo = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12)
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    observaciones = models.TextField()
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class OrdenCompra(TimeStampedModel):
    codigo = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12)
    cotizacion = models.ForeignKey(Cotizacion, null=True)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5)
    observaciones = models.TextField()
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Con la posibilidad de que se cree una orden de compra sin necesidad de tener una cotización, por lo que estoy pensando agregar el campo "proveedor" al Modelo OrdenCompra, mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Es correcto hacer eso o hay alguna otra forma de trabajarlo? Ya que en caso de que exista la cotización, para poder acceder al proveedor, simplemente utilizo al proveedor de la cotización y sino tendría que guardar a mi proveedor directamente en la orden de compra.

Eso me lleva a otro problema similar, esta vez con los detalles de cada uno:

```
class DetalleCotizacion(TimeStampedModel):
    nro_detalle = models.IntegerField()
    cotizacion = models.ForeignKey(Cotizacion)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    cantidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5)
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class DetalleOrdenCompra(TimeStampedModel):
    nro_detalle = models.IntegerField()
    orden = models.ForeignKey(OrdenCompra)
    detalle_cotizacion = models.ForeignKey(DetalleCotizacion, null=True)
    cantidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5)
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5)
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Con la misma posibilidad anterior de crear el detalle de la orden de compra directamente sin tener un detalle de cotización agregando para ello el campo "producto" al modelo DetalleOrdenCompra.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola inkarri, no me queda claro si se tratan de dos situaciones diferentes o dos ejemplos diferentes de la misma situación. Si son dos cosas diferentes, deberías separarlos. Por otro lado, no veo que expongas un problema real, más bien, solicitas opiniones. Te invito a que leas [esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) y consideres la posibilidad de modificar tu pregunta para que se ajuste a los estándares de calidad del sitio.

Comment: Muchas gracias veo que no era la forma mas adecuada de formular la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

En la primera situación puedes colocar el proveedor en los dos modelos. En el segundo caso el campo `detalle_cotizacion` en `DetalleOrdenCompra` no es necesario ya que podrías acceder a el desde la orden: `myorden.cotizacion__detallecotizacion_set.all()`